# Beginner CSS Question

Tags: css, xhtml

Why do the bg and header not overlap?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>My First CSS Webpage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="bg" src="bg.jpg"/>
    <img class="header" src="header.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
    #bg{
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
    }
    #header{
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

Use a `.` instead of a `#` or change `class=` to `id=`

I recommend the latter because I'm assuming that `bg` and `header` are **unique**.

```
<img id="bg" src="bg.jpg"/>
<img id="header" src="header.png"/>
```

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

The two images in the html have been given classes, while in your css you define styles for ids.

If the element has a class, target it in css using .classname, if it has an id target it using #idname. If the element only occurs once in the html, use id. If there are multiple occurences, use a class.

Answer (score 0):

also, I would suggest for 2 elements which use the same basic properties
to define them as:

```
#element1, #element2
{
/* css properties */
}
```

This will save space on your css file, and can add up to quite alot.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, a class selector is a name preceded by a full stop (“.”) and an ID selector is a name preceded by a hash character (“#”).

The HTML refers to the CSS by using the attributes id and class.

The difference between an ID and a class is that an ID can be used to identify one element, whereas a class can be used to identify more than one.

you can not use class in your HTML file and use a hash character (“#”) in your CSS file to style a particular element.